# why cannot see the in-memory table that I created through JAVA API from DolphinDB GUI?

Tags: java, database, api, dolphindb

I created a in-memory table "t1" and loaded data into it through DolphinDB Java API. Then I started DolphinDG java GUI, "select * from t1", why "t1" cannot be recognized?

Answer (score 0):

`t1` is a local variable in the session created by the Java API connection, which is invisible to other sessions. GUI connection created a new session. If you would like to see `t1` across all sessions, please share `t1`